# how can the string convert to int in python?

Tags: python, numpy

In **Machine learning in action** Chapter 2, one example reads records from file, each line like:

```
124  110 223 largeDoses
```

(forget its actual meaning)

One function in `kNN.py` is:

```
 def file2matrix(filename):
      fr = open(filename)
      numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())        
      returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))       
      classLabelVector = []                       
      fr = open(filename)
      index = 0
      for line in fr.readlines():
          line = line.strip()
          listFromLine = line.split('\t')
          returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
          classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
         index += 1
     return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

The problem is `listFromLine[-1]` is a string (`'largeDoses'`, etc.), how can it convert to `int`?

In the book, it says `numpy` can handle this.

(From the book : **You have to explicitly tell the interpreter that you’d like the integer version of the last item in the list, or it will give you the string version. Usually, you’d have to do this, but NumPy takes care of those details for you.**)
However,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'largeDoses'
```

occurs for

```
import kNN
kNN.file2matrix('dataset.txt')
```

BTW, the book's Chinese version is different from English Version.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you convert `largeDoses` to an integer? What value should it give you? Do you have a mapping of string-int pairs?

Comment: In the book, it says numPy can handle this. => so what is expected output of int('largeDoses')?

Comment: An error is expected

Comment: the LabelsVector in the output from book is : [3,1,2,....]. The code doesn't have any mapping of string-int.

Comment: If you don't have a mapping, then there's nothing you can do. Python (or NumPy) can't magically convert a word to an integer arbitrarily.

Comment: Originally, I think so. Is it possible that the code is wrong in the book 'Machine learning in action'? You can refer to that book. @netcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String (indeed) cannot convert to int, neither in python, nor in other environment,

however,

the solution is

### Put Machine Learning (indeed) in action

In case all `kNN`-input training / cross-validation records ( a.k.a. observations, examples )

do conform to the convention of `[ 3x FEATURE, 1x LABEL]`

use:

```
classLabelVector.append( listFromLine[-1] )    # to .append a LABEL, not an int()
```

Comment: Ok, so the code is wrong,right? BTW, I originally read its Chinese translation version, and I then found its output of 'LabelsVector' is different from English version. (the former's output is Int, the later output is String)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert those 'largeDoses' 'smallDoses' 'didntLike' to the number by hand. String cannot convert to int unless the String inside is int.

```
if (listLine[-1]=='largeDoses'):
    listLine[-1] = '3'
elif (listLine[-1]=='smallDoses'):
    listLine[-1] = '2'
else:
    listLine[-1] = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen that instead of simply changing the string to integer data, it is changed to a table. So, the modification program is as follows.

```
labels = {'didntLike':1,'smallDoses':2,'largeDoses':3}
classLabelVector.append(labels[listFromLine[-1]])
```